# How Do I Switch Views With PageControl & UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, xib, uipagecontrol

I'm a noob to Iphone development (3rd day in Xcode) and I am trying to implement pageControl and scrollview so users can swipe between various pages.  I'm using [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/) tutorial and I can't figure out how to load/switch views from nib files as opposed to just changing the background color of a view.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

Modification of PageControlExampleViewController.m renamed NewsClass2

```
// Creates the color list the first time this method is invoked. Returns one color object from the list.
+ (UIColor *)pageControlColorWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (__pageControlColorList == nil) {
    __pageControlColorList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor magentaColor],
                              [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor brownColor], [UIColor grayColor], nil];
}
// Mod the index by the list length to ensure access remains in bounds.
return [__pageControlColorList objectAtIndex:index % [__pageControlColorList count]];
}

//Changing views instead of colors, not working
+ (UIView *)pageControlViewWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (__pageControlViewrList == nil) {
    __pageControlViewrList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil],
                              [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], [[UIView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PageView" bundle:nil], nil];
}
// Mod the index by the list length to ensure access remains in bounds.
return [__pageControlViewList objectAtIndex:index % [__pageControlViewList count]];
}

// Set the label and background color when the view has finished loading.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
pageNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber + 1];
self.view.backgroundColor = [NewsClass2 pageControlColorWithIndex:pageNumber];
//Setting View Not Working
self.view = [NewsClass2 pageControlViewWithIndex:pageNumber];
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to scroll to a particular 'page' in the scrollview? Anyway the tutorial is weird in that it sets the text and background color in viewDidLoad like that. Doesn't each view in the scrollview have that set already? so just show that part of the scrollview. Didn't really go through it in that much detail. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Objective C.

First of all you need to set delegate of scroll view like

```
//in .h file write

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>



// in viewDidLoad

self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

then write in delegate method of UIScrollView write...

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

then make an IBAction of valueChange for pageControl like .....

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender
{
    int page = self.pageControlHelp.currentPage;
    CGRect frame = self.scrollViewHelp.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollViewHelp scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

And you have done .......

If you have any confusion for this please feel free to ask......